# Random Access files in c++

Tags: c++, filestream, random-access

Hi i could not specific Record from my binary file. This is the method to list out all records.

```
int student :: showall(fstream &fp)
{
    student rec;
    fp.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    int i=0;
    cout<<"Position\tRoll No\t\tName\tBalance"<<endl;
    while(fp.read((char*)&rec,sizeof rec))
    {   
        cout<<i*sizeof rec<<"\t";
        rec.show();
        i++;
    }
}
```

While running this i got the below output

> ```
>  Position Roll No     Name    Balance 0       1
>  Heartly  10 28       2       
>  Heartly  20 56       3       
>  Heartly  30 84       4       
>  Heartly  40 112      5
>  Heartly  50 140      6       
>  Heartly  60 168      7       
>  Heartly  70 196      8
>  Heartly  80 224      9       
>  Heartly  90 252      10      
>  Heartly  100
> ```

Now i want to search specific record. I gave RecNo 5 to search. This is my View method

```
int student :: view(fstream &fp,int RecNum)
{
    student rec;
    std::ios::pos_type SearchPosition = RecNum*sizeof rec;
    cout<<endl<<"Position="<<SearchPosition<<endl;
    if( fp.seekg(SearchPosition) == 0 )
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Position="<<SearchPosition<<endl;
            if(fp.read((char*)&rec,sizeof rec))
                    rec.show();
        else
            cout<<endl<<"Read Error .. ! "<<endl;
        }
    else
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Record Number Not Found"<<endl;
    }   
}
```

After running this method , i got below result.

> Record number (-1 Cancels):  5
>
> Position=140
>
> Record Number Not Found

Why it is not locating the specific Record?

```
printf("\nMenu : AddDummy, Add, View, Edit, List or Quit ( U, A, V, E, L or Q) : ");  switch(toupper(getchar()))  {     
     case 'U' :
        file.open("abc.cli",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);
            cout<<"Creating dummy file of 1000 entries"<<endl;
            record.adddummy(file);
        file.clear();
            break;
    case 'A' :
        file.open("abc.cli",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);
            record.get();
        record.add(record,file);
            cout<<"Record Added"<<endl;         
            file.clear();
            break;              
    case 'E' :      
            file.open("abc.cli",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::ate);
            cout<<endl<<"Record number (-1 Cancels): "<<endl;
            cin>>Rec;
            if (Rec > -1){
                record.get();
         if(!record.update(record,file,Rec))
            cout<<"Record Edited"<<endl;            
             else
            cout<<"Record Edited Failed"<<endl;     
        file.clear();}
             break;
    case 'V' :      
             file.open("abc.cli",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::ate);
             cout<<endl<<"Record number (-1 Cancels): "<<endl;
             cin>>Rec;
             if (Rec > -1)
                record.view(file,Rec);
         file.clear();
             break;
    case 'L' :
         file.open("abc.cli",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::ate);
             record.showall(file); 
         file.clear();
             break; 
    case 'Q' :
            file.close();
        return 0;   
    default :
        cout<<" \nNot Matching\n ";     
}while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Why its not reading the specific Record?enter code here

Comment: I tried to format the input, I don't think I managed. Can you clean it up further?

Comment: You should read a little more about the `seekg` method, specially what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

`fstream::seekg`returns a fstream reference, will never be equal 0. So the condition you are checking will never runs. [fstream::seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/)

Comment: Thank You so much !! again one question? In the switch statement if i give 'L' to list out, The first time its listing all. But if i again give 'L' means, it doesn't listing any thing? But the control are passed to showall method. But it doesn't enter into read statement. why?

Comment: You are re-opening the file, why?. If you re-open the file, the failbit flag is set so, access you made after is incorrect.

Comment: correct !! thanks for yr help !! but how can i check whether the file is written or not?